# Object reference is not set -- WPF -- Rows Deletion

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress

I am using WPF and Devxpress. I made two operations in my application that are to add and to delete row from grid. Both are working fine. But if i drag an drop a column then deletion stops to work to delete multiple rows at same time. Here code and image, Please answer my query.

```
 private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

      if (DXMessageBox.Show("Are You Sure, you Want to Delete?", "Delete Item-Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)

            {
        try
            {
                myEntities dbcontext = new myEntities();
                Name per = grid.SelectedItem as Name;
                dbcontext.Names.Remove(per);
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                Refresh();
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
           DXMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

            }}}
```

[image]

Where this code below is working very fine to delete a single row:

```
Name per = grid.SelectedItem as Name; 
dbcontext.Names.Remove(per); 
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @Arun .... is image not visible to you? go here http://i.stack.imgur.com/yr8yw.png

Comment: to delete multiple rows, you need traverse using foreach and delete each row invidually from dbcontext]

Comment: @Arun  i tried it too. can you provide me some sample code lines.

Comment: @Arun should i set Selection mode to "Row", but it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty instance of `dbcontext` and then trying to modify an object within the empty instance, which is non-existent.

Make a global instance (at class level) of myEntities type, which will hold the original instance with all the objects. Then at the event, simply access that global instance and modify the objects in it.

Comment: what do you mean by empty instance ? it has object

Comment: hi, thank you for reply . But if i used . .. Name per  = grid.SelectedItem as Name;
                dbcontext.Names.Remove(per);
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();  ......... to delete a single row, IT WORKS FINE

Answer (score 0):

try this...get all selected items from datagrid...

```
myEntities dbcontext = new myEntities();
foreach (var item in grid.SelectedItems)
      {
                Name per = item as Name;
                dbcontext.Names.Remove(per);
       }
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT**
I don't know about devexpress datagrid, but you may get help from [DevExpress grid multiple row data selection](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7362)

Comment: thank you for providing code lines. but it says that : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: please change selection mode on DataGrid

Comment: i am using devexpress grid, there are no such options in it.

Comment: try google or devexpress documentation  to find selected multiple rows in devexpress grid

Comment: should i set Selection mode to "Row", but it is also not working